# How to get ARM Docker images when creating devcontainer is VS Code? (mac m1)

Tags: macos, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

After buying a new mac M1, I decided to reinstall existing vscode devcontainers, using the *Clone Repository in container Volume* feature.

It kind of worked but then, I immediately noticed it was very slow, buggy, and used QEMU.

After reading this on [Docker M1 official Page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/):

> However, attempts to run Intel-based containers on Apple M1 machines can crash as QEMU sometimes fails to run the container. Therefore, we recommend that you run ARM64 containers on M1 machines. These containers are also faster and use less memory than Intel-based containers.

I understood I was running Intel images under emulation, and I should not do that.

To build these containers, I had picked images from MCR ([here](https://hub.docker.com/publishers/microsoftowner)).
On all of them, I notice a "x86-64" tag, no mention about ARM. Does that mean Microsoft provides actually no official ARM image?

If so, how am I supposed to do to have clean dev containers using ARM images? Should I wait an MCR update? Or should I pick other images, not Microsoft ones?
Am I missing something?

---

I'm using:

- VS Code 1.54.1
- Docker Desktop Preview 3.1.0 (60984)
- Mac OS BigSur 11.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the specific MCR containers, you will need to wait for them to be available for arm64.

However, if you do not need the specific image, you have ample amount of Docker images that are build for arm64 and can be found in the Docker HUB. You can search for `arm64v8` or search for the image and check if the `arm64` tag is displayed

In both cases, you can try to pull any image for `linux/arm64` platform architecture as follows:

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 image
```

Final option is for you to build your own image. This can be a time consuming since you might face the need to port some of the libraries to arm64v8.

Answer (score 2):

Update, there are now many to choose from:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/issues/558#issuecomment-910369599

This wont age well, but I don't want to post an answer with nothing. As of 9/9/21:

```
Base images

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:dev-bullseye (Debian 11) - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:dev-stretch (Debian 9) - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:dev-hirsute (Ubuntu 21.04) - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:dev-bionic (Ubuntu 18.04) - Released in v0.194.2
Node

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:dev-16-bullseye - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:dev-14-bullseye - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:dev-12-bullseye - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:dev-16-bullseye - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:dev-14-bullseye - Released in v0.194.2
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:dev-12-bullseye - Released in v0.194.2
Python

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:dev-3-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:dev-3.9-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:dev-3.8-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:dev-3.7-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:dev-3.6-bullseye
PHP

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:dev-8-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:dev-8.0-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:dev-7-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:dev-7.4-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/php:dev-7.3-bullseye
Go

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:dev-1-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:dev-1.17-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:dev-1.16-bullseye
Ruby

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:dev-1-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:dev-1.17-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:dev-1.16-bullseye
Ruby, Jekyll

mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/ruby:dev-3.0-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/ruby:dev-2.7-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/ruby:dev-2.6-bullseye
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/jekyll:dev-bullseye
```

Comment: FWIW I have been using the `typescript-node:dev-12-bullseye` version on my M1 mbp and it's been much faster than the comparable intel version that forces qemu simulation. I also thought it was worth using this (rather than a vanilla linux/arm64 image) bc there are a lot of prebuilt scripts that help setting up a non-root user with sudo access, importing credentials, etc. that made it much easier overall to get it up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Following jordanvrtanoski answer,

I decided to use official Docker images that are natively compatible with arm64.
In the between, I realized MCR images have nothing crazy or impossible to reproduce. They provide base templates they use for their images [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/container-templates)

As I use root user in my containers, and don't need many additional binaries, the only thing I picked from these MCR images is the customization of bashrc file, to have custom prompt, colors on `ls` cmd, and aliases.

Everything works as expected, and it's cleaner since each line of my Dockerfile is now known, and useful to me.