Can't debug azure function in devcontainer
We are using devcontainers and tried to run a Azure-Function via Azure Functions vs code extension. When we try to execute the function via  func host start we get rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
The code builds, but can't start. There is also a .Net Aspire Application, hosting a ASP.Net Core and a nodejs server in the Project where debugging works fine.
This happens on a Mac M1 Machine. The devcontainer image is based on
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:8.0-bookworm

This question is similar to: qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@akseli my question is not about building the docker image. It is about executing a command inside a running docker container instance.

Based on the error, it's being thrown by rosetta, which would indicate that it's actually an issue with the devcontain's platform. Because you're running on ARM, you'll need the platform specific devcontainer for everything to work correctly as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493499/how-to-get-arm-docker-images-when-creating-devcontainer-is-vs-code-mac-m1
